# Network 1 cant' see Network 2 - Both have DHCP

Tags: networking, router

Ok so this is the current setup:

**Network 1:**

- Has its own DHCP
- Is connected to a ADSL low speed connection and runs the Phone lines
- Has the network 192.168.2.1 (gateway)

**Network 2:**

- Has its own DHCP
- Is connected to a high speed ADSL2 connection and runs for the office computers.
- Has the network 192.168.1.1 (gateway)

Currently Network 1 cannot see Network 2 and vice versa.

I tried the following but I feel like I'm missing something:

- I plugged Router1 into router2  (from eth1 port to eth1 port of the other router) and set a static route from router2 to router 1 for (192.168.2.1/24).

What are the issues with doing this? Am I missing something crucial? Do I also need to set it on the other router as well perhaps? This is not working currently.

Additionally, when I type in 192.168.2.1 to access the router of the network 1 from network 2 , I still only get the router of network 2 now... so both 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 go to the same router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining two networks requires (by definition!) a *gateway*, *i.e.* a host with two network interfaces, one belonging to network1, the other one to network2, allowing packets to pass from one to the other. In other words, this requires either a commercial router (to be configured to act as gateway only, not a router), or a specially crafted pc (it would be trivial to do with Linux). As a matter of fact, for a SOHO even an inexpensive Raspberry Pi would do.

There is however a much cheaper solution: unify the two nets into a single one, and you will have no need to buy or refit anything. This requires one word of caution: you need to disable the DHCP server on **one** of your two routers, **or** (if you decide to leave both DHCP servers running) you need to make sure that the two pools from which IP addresses are taken *do not overlap*.

A concrete example. You assign IP address 192.168.3.1 to router1 (LAN side, of course) and 192.168.3.129 to router2 (again LAN side). Then you can have the following ranges:

> Router1 192.168.3.2-192.168.3.127
>
> Router2 192.168.3.129-192.168.3.254

leaving as network mask 255.255.255.0 (or /24).

At this point you  can draw an ethernet cable between the two routers (draw an ethernet cable from each of them to the same switch, it's the same), restart all of your machines (or allow some time for the new info to propagate to all of your hosts), and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I"m using an EdgeMAX conneted to an N600 Router. Would I need to set any static route or do any further configuration on either of the routings. Once I've made both of the changes on each router for Ip ranges?

Comment: There is no need to adjust routes outside your LAN,and thus on the routers. However, if there are some host which you definitely want to go through one of the routers (say router1),  you will have to give them static IP addresses which explicitly indicate router1 as their router, instead of router2. The other hosts, those with dynamic IPs, will choose their router randomly.

Comment: Hi Marius, ok so no public routes but what about a private static route? - Certain hosts should only go through router 1 and router 2 which is working but they still cant' see ping each other at this time - http://gyazo.com/660c130f65086a3b21556afc8818dcc5 - is this correct?

Comment: @user7751 It takes some times for the changes in IP address to propagate. As this happens, some hosts will appear unreachable. Total time? perhaps 1 hour. Countermeasure? Turn **everything** off, turn on both routers only,  wait 30 seconds, turn everything else back on.